# how to connect midi input to python callback in Ableton control surface

Tags: python, midi, ableton-live

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't figure out the best way to do it. I just want to connect a set of arbitrary midi input messages to various API controlling methods in my control surface. Do I need to make ButtonElements for *every* message I want handled? Is there no generic "midi in" kinda thing? And how is one best supposed to attach these to methods?

thanks!
Iain

Comment: If answers you want, accept answers you should.

Comment: Can you show some code you have now, and which methods of the Ableton API you're using?